# Broken after upgrading from Froala 2.9 to 3.0.x in Angular

Tags: angular, froala

I am wondering if anyone has run into similar issue after upgrading from Froala 2.9.x to 3.0.x where code no longer works. The biggest issue right now i have in my Angular / reactive Form deployment is that i no longer get a reference to my component instance. The code i used before which worked was this.

```
private setFroalaOptions(componentInstance) {
        this.froalaOptions = {
            key: environment.froala.license.version3,
            charCounter: true,
            charCounterCount: true,
            toolbarSticky: false,
            attribution: false,
            // zIndex: 2501,
            // zIndex: 10,
            height: 300,
            ...this.froalaUploadService.initUploadOptions(),
            ...this.froalaUploadService.initImageManagerOptions(),
            events : {
                'froalaEditor.focus' : function(e, editor) {
                    // componentInstance.editorInstance = editor;
                },
                'froalaEditor.blur' : function(e, editor) {
                    // save selection so we can restore just before inserting any element
                    editor.selection.save();
                },
                'froalaEditor.initialized' : function(e, editor) {
                    componentInstance.editorInstance = editor;
                },
                ...this.froalaUploadService.initImageManagerEvents(),
                ...this.froalaUploadService.initUploadEvents(),
            },
            toolbarButtons: ToolbarButtons,
        };
    }
```

then i was able to call the below code to insert values at the current cursor position of the editor

```
  addField($event: IServerDropdownOption) {
        if (this.editorInstance) {
            // restore selection so element is inserted in the cursor's last known position
            this.editorInstance.selection.restore();
            this.editorInstance.html.insert(`${$event.value}`);
        }
    }
```

now that i no longer have the **this.editorInstance** i does not work and i cant find any docs which outline any possible changes which might have broken this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their docs, I believe the event function context (i.e. `this`) is the editor instance.

```
// FROM DOCS
new FroalaEditor('.selector', {
  events: {
    'focus': function () {
      // Do something here.
      // this is the editor instance.
      console.log(this);
    })
  }
});
```

Link to docs: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#focus

---

Which means you should be able to do something like:

```
'focus' : function() {
  // componentInstance.editorInstance = this;
},
```

---

Full example for your scenario:

```
private setFroalaOptions(componentInstance) {
        this.froalaOptions = {
            key: environment.froala.license.version3,
            charCounter: true,
            charCounterCount: true,
            toolbarSticky: false,
            attribution: false,
            // zIndex: 2501,
            // zIndex: 10,
            height: 300,
            ...this.froalaUploadService.initUploadOptions(),
            ...this.froalaUploadService.initImageManagerOptions(),
            events : {
                'focus' : function() {
                    // componentInstance.editorInstance = this;
                },
                'blur' : function() {
                    // save selection so we can restore just before inserting any element
                    this.selection.save();
                },
                'initialized' : function() {
                    componentInstance.editorInstance = this;
                },
                ...this.froalaUploadService.initImageManagerEvents(), // make sure to update these
                ...this.froalaUploadService.initUploadEvents(), // make sure to update these
            },
            toolbarButtons: ToolbarButtons,
        };
    }
```

Comment: If you look at my code I am using that syntax ? You think I have to drop the frolaEditor from focus ?

Comment: In your code you're passing the `editor` as an argument to the event function `function(e, editor)`. According to the docs it's not longer an argument, but the function context itself (`this`).

And yes, according to the docs the "froalaEditor." is no longer in the event name.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example for your scenario. I verified that `this` is equivalent to the `editorInstance` in my personal app.

Comment: Yes that did the trick,  so they no longer use the froalaEditor prefix as well as they got away with the extra stuff and you use this to get access to the editor instance